# AWS SignatureDoesNotMatch most of the times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know this has been asked a lot, but in my case it's sometimes working and sometimes not.

I tried to benchmark it and roughly 30 second of each 10 minutes it's working.

The service (django, python, boto3) runs on aws fargate, so I assume it's clocked in correct.

I know that this is not much to debug but I am looking FOR ANY HINTS, MAY THEY BE FAR FETCHED to start debugging this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It vanished after a few hours. I don't know why.